# Append data into HTML file

Tags: javascript, html, json, api

I am looking to append the data shown from my internal npm api into an html file. What is the best way to append the data into a html file ?

Include football data npm package

```js
var data = require("footballdata-api-v2");
var FootballData = data.default;   
var footballData = new FootballData("API-Key");
```

Get teams information data from api package

```js
footballData.getTeamsFromCompetition({
    competitionId: 2021  
})
    .then(function(data) {
        // Logs information from api in console
        console.log(JSON.stringify(data.teams, null, 4));
        var { teams: [{ table: tableData }] } = data;
        document.getElementById("output").innerHTML += rowDataHTML;
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `rowDataHtml` is what you want to append to the `#output` element, which I am assuming it to be a table, you can try something like this:

```js
const {teams} = data;
count output = document.getElementById("output");

teams.forEach(({table: tableData}) => {
    const rowDataHtml = `
        <tr>
            <td>${tableData.name}</td>
            <td>${tableData.league}</td>
            <td>${tableData.country}</td>
            <td>${tableData.score}</td>
        </tr>
    `;

    output.innerHTML += rowDataHTML;
});
```